# Chrome extension. JS works on popup window and not on main window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome-extension

So, I have trouble. I am making a chrome extension, I have popup.html (window with credits), content.js, background.js (that works on click). Main trouble is that when I click on icon of extension background.js getting that I clicked it and starts working on popup page and not on the page I needed. I've tried to make it in popup.js, but same thing, it is working in popup.html page and not on the main page. How to change js code?
 
Main part of content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if( request.message === "clicked_browser_action" ) {
        var name = window.location.href;
        subject = name.substr(name.indexOf("/",1)+2,name.indexOf("-",1)-name.indexOf("/",1)-2);
        exam = name.substr(name.indexOf("-",1)+1,name.indexOf(".",1)-name.indexOf("-",1)-1);
        myLoop();
    }
  }
);
```

background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});
  });
});
```

Comment: [`browserAction.onClicked`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked) does _**not**_ fire if the browser action has a popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you include content.js in popup.html. This is wrong. Content scripts are for web pages but the browser_action (or page_action) popup is an extension page with its own `chrome-extension://` URL, DOM, window, `document`. In Chrome browser you can inspect it by right-clicking inside the popup, then clicking "inspect". See also [How to access the webpage DOM?](/a/4532567)

Solution:

- remove content.js from popup.html
- write a separate popup.js
- since chrome.browserAction.onClicked won't work when you have a popup you'll also move its contents into popup.js so it'll run each time the popup is shown

popup.html:

```
<script src=popup.js></script>
```

popup.js:

```
// this will run every time the popup is shown
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  var activeTab = tabs[0];
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});
});
```